# Calculate d for RSA

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to calculate $d$. I have the following parameters given:

$p = 239$

$q = 181$

$n = p \times q = 43259$

$\phi(n) = (p - 1) \times (q - 1) = 42840$

$e = 11$

For calculating $d$ I use the Euclidean Algorithm:

$a = qb + r$

$42840 = 3894 \times 11 + 6$

$11 = 1 \times 6 + 5$

$6 = 1 \times 5 + 1$

$5 = 5 \times 1 + 0$

This leads me to this table here:

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
a & b & q & r & x & y \\ \hline
42840 & 11 & 3894 & 6 & 2 & -7789 \\ \hline
11 & 6 & 1 & 5 & -1 & 2 \\ \hline
6 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
5 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

When I check this solution, everything is fine:

$1 = 42840 \times 2 + 11 \times (-7789)$

but my $d$ should be $35051$, because I need $e \times d  = 1 \bmod 42840$.

We can check this via encryption and decryption as well.
Let's say I encrypt the number $6$:

$E(M) = M^e \bmod n = 6^{11} \bmod 43259 = 27082$

The decryption works fine for $d=35051$

$D(C) = C^d \bmod n = 27082^{35051} \bmod 43259 = 6$

But it's wrong for $-7789$.

So, what did I do wrong to calculate $d$? Can you provide a full path to $d$?

Comment: The full Euclidean algorithm is overkill and error prone due to sign issues. See the 10-step method starting _"the half-extended Euclidean algorithm can be used to efficiently compute $a^{-1}\bmod b$ .."_ [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54447/555), which uses only non-negative integers. Independently: computations are slightly easier ($d$ is often smaller) if you use $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ rather than $\varphi(n)$, and that's mandated by official standard [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=59).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this link. Really interesting, I really appreciate this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that $42840 - 7789 = 35051$.

Comment: oh, why do I need to calculate `42840 - 7789`? I always thought that `y` would be already the solution. Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: RSA calculations are using unsigned integers, basically you're operating in the group defined by the modulus. So -7789 is identical to 35051 within the calculations - if you allow it to exist at all.

Comment: ok, but why not using + instead of -? I understand that I need to operate in unsigned integers, but I don't understand why I need to subtract y from phi.

Comment: The point is that $35051 \equiv -7789 \pmod{42840}$, meaning $35051 = -7789 + 42840 k$ for some integer $k$.  In this case, $k = 1$.  What it means is that the euclidean algorithm gave you an equivalent representative of the remainder.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. It's clear now :)